# Putting anything in the constructor of Angular component results in failure of entire page

Tags: html, angular, constructor, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to add something to the constructor of one of my Angular components, however, anytime I put something in the constructor, it renders the entire page blank - getting rid of all of the other components and displaying just the background.

For example - this will work.

**TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardboxes',
  templateUrl: './cardboxes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardboxes.component.scss']
})
export class CardboxesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  
}
```

And this will render completely blank - removing everything, even the other components.

**TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardboxes',
  templateUrl: './cardboxes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardboxes.component.scss']
})
export class CardboxesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  
}
```

For the record, it doesn't matter what is put in the constructor - it is the same result every time. The Chrome terminal says that there is a NullInjectorError - No provider for MatDialog

Is there a reason for this, or an easy solution? I do not understand why this is happening and I really need to be able to use the constructors. Do I have to make another import somewhere? Is there a configuration I am missing?

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: No, there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Can you share the stackblitz of your code?

Comment: How do I make a stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use angular materials. Please use this comand in console.
npm i @angular/material
Open app.module and

NgModule ({....
imports: [...,
MatSliderModule,
…]

Comment: I think I already had this imported. However, I did run the terminal command and checked app.module and it all seems to be in order?

Comment: Run your project. Open in chrome. Press right click and inspect. Press console any errors there?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes there is an error here. It says:

NullInjectorError - No provider for MatDialog. 

Do you know how to go about resolving this?

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/

Comment: You did not import correctly in module. See example here

Comment: In app.module.ts? What should my app.module.ts look like?

Comment: Please see this example step 1 https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/

Comment: In newer versions of angular you can use `ng add @angular/material` and it will help you to setup the basics. https://angular.io/cli/add

Answer (score 0):

Items adsed in constructor should be imported in module

Comment: How do I go about doing that exactly?

Comment: A good answer needs to give more information, enough for the person who asked the question to apply the answer.

Comment: This may help https://dev.to/jwp/mat-dialog-in-10-minutes-4808